# Windows crashes on performing Process.start many times

Tags: c#, .net, process.start

I have a Shell application and I perform a process.start to run other applications from my Shell application. I came across a weird scenario where in, I launch Notepad many times from my shell applications and after say 30 times, the application crashes and topmost notepad window keeps blinking and finally logs off the system.

```
 ProcessStartInfo process    = new ProcessStartInfo();
 process.FileName            = ExePath;
 process.Arguments           = Parameter;
 Process newProcess          = Process.Start(process);
```

This is how I start my process.

Comment: What exception application throws when crash?

Comment: I dont get any exception. I was waiting for an exception at the try catch block but nothing at all. I even put a global try catch but nothing came through there as well.